# Mongoose query MongoDB, find() object inside an object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Hello I have an Schema on Mongoose but have and object inside

```
const TrajesDeBano = new Schema({
    modelo:{type:String, required: true},
    tipo:{type:String, required:true},
    talla:[{
        s:{type:Number, required: true},
        m:{type:Number, required: true},
        l:{type:Number, required: true}
    }],
    precio:{type:Number, required: true}
});
```

when I do a callback to call "talla" returns an object

```
traje.findOne({'modelo':modelo}, function(err, trajeEncontrado){
      console.log(trajeEncontrado.talla)
});
```

**[ {_id:5dd177918c7f021e4cab7e20, s: 15, m: 30, l: 25} ]**

now I wanna call every "talla" singleone but a query **trajeEncontrado.talla.s**
returns **undefined**. How can I find just the talla "S"?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will return undefined because of it don't know the array is, you could `$unwind` them or using `$elemMatch`

using `$elemeMatch`

```js
Model.find({ modelo: 'Your Modelo', talla: { $elemMatch: { s: 2 } } })
```

See [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html)